# Swift 2 JSON Byte array to UIImage

Tags: ios, json, uiimage

My IOS app is retrieving a JSON Object containing a field "file" which is an image.
This field is encoded by the server in Base 64

```
JSON Serialization: Optional({
file = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/........
```

I would need to load this field in an UIImageView. I tried multiple ways without any success. here is an extract of my code:

```
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {

            let json: AnyObject?
            let imageArray: NSData?
            do{
            try json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
                imageArray = json!["file"] as? NSData
                print("JSON file: \(imageArray)")

            }
        catch
        {
            print("error Serialization")
            return
        }
```

but imageArray is nil...any idea how I can retrieve this field (Base 64 Byte array) and convert it in an UIImage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON cannot contain binary data. It can only contain Strings, Numbers, Booleans and Nulls. You need to convert the base64 String to NSData yourself.

Replace the line `imageArray = json!["file"] as? NSData` to the following 5 lines.

```
if let fileBase64 = json!["file"] as? String {
    imageArray = NSData(base64EncodedString: fileBase64, options: [])
} else {
    print("missing `file` entry")
}
```

Comment: ok, and how can I convert imageArray to UIImage ? I tried self.ordoPhoto.image = UIImage(data: imageArray!) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Clarify what you mean with "it doesn't work"? Does it generate a build-time error? Causes your app crash? or always `nil` or something other?

Comment: sorry for being unclear....my UIImageView ordoPhoto remains blank....even if I copy my imageArray by using self.ordoPhoto.image = UIImage(data: imageArray!)

Comment: Check if `imageArray` is nil or not.

Comment: it is not, I can print it, the content is finally there

Comment: Then the data may be broken or in an unsupported image format. If you can save the binary content of the NSData into a file, you can check it by opening  the file.

Comment: in fact it is working fine..it was just very long to display the picture on the simulator.....thks OOPer ! btw how can I do the opposite, means convert a UIIMage into a Base 64 byte array ?

Comment: Happy to hear it's working. And "the opposite"  is another issue. Please search on the web, and if you cannot find one good solution, post it as your new question.